# DropDown place in top of other element css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried putting a [dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKrpX.png) but hes not on top of other elements. I tried puting `z-index` but still no luck. I've make the `position: 'relative'` but the element got pushed down when hovering on the dropdown button.

heres the site http://jaysonvelagio.webprodigymedia.com/

```
<div id="believe-belong">
    <div class="site-width">
        <div class="two-col">
            <div class="two-col-one image">
                <img src="assets/image/dine.jpg" alt="CLICKTREP Dining Privileges" />
            </div><!-- .two-col-one.image -->

            <div class="two-col-two">
                <h3 class="green">Dine</h3>
                <p>Taste your favorite mouthwatering dish for less on restaurants/Café/Bakeshop of your choice all over the Metro. Take advantage of the regular discounts and perks whenever you visit our partners.</p>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                          <button class="dropbtn">partners in dine</button>
                          <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>  
            </div><!-- .two-col-two -->
        </div><!-- .row.two-col -->

    </div><!-- .site-width -->
</div><!-- #believe-belong -->


<div id="gray-back">
    <div class="site-width">
        <div class="two-col" >  
            <div class="two-col-two">
                <h3 class="green">Shop</h3>
                <p>Instant Discounts anytime from today’s best Shopping stores. <br>Like Toby’s Sport, RUNNR, Ideal Vision and a lot more. </p>
                <a href="clubmembers/blog.php" class="button">Partner Stores</a>    
            </div><!-- .two-col-two -->
            <div class="two-col-one image">
                <img src="assets/image/shop.jpg" alt="CLICKTREP Dining Privileges" />
            </div><!-- .two-col-one.image -->       
        </div><!-- .row.two-col -->

    </div><!-- .site-width -->
</div><!-- #believe-belong -->
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: i got the code here for drop down buttons http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Comment: Update your question with a minimal code example of your problem

Comment: cant you just look the site? and inspect the element?

Comment: the site is here http://jaysonvelagio.webprodigymedia.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had a play with your code in the website and seems your issue is a bit more complex to solve than you think.

The reason you won't get that dropdown is that you have overflow:hidden on the parent div with class `two-col`.

Now if you try and add overflow:visible to that it messes with the whole DOM structure as you can see:

[image]

The only way you can fix this is to add overflow:visible to your div and see how you can rearrange the structure.

UPDATE:

I had another play with it with only adding `overflow-y:visible`. This time it doesn't mess with the UI but adds a scrollbar to that div. If that's OK you can proceed with this one.

```
.two-col {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: visible;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am also thinking that this dropdown cant be placed here